# Birdseye Viewer in other applications?

Tags: leaflet, google-maps-api, bing-maps, esri-leaflet

has anyone used Bing Maps Birdseye Viewer tiles in other applications? I have seen [Leaflet Bing](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins) but it looks like it just has aerial, aerial with labels and road tiles. Does it have birdseye tiles? Is there anything else that I could access birdseye tiles on?

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to overlay JSON files on the birdseye tiles.

Comment: old discussion but check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983435/is-there-any-api-to-download-45-degree-aerial-imagery-birds-eye-from-bing

Answer (score 1):

The Birdseye tiles cannot be used outside of the Bing Maps controls. This is a restriction in the Bing Maps terms of use.

You can use the Bing Maps V7 JavaScript control to view Birdseye imagery and overlay your JSON file data on top of that. The Bing Maps controls display any data that is added to the map when viewing Birdseye imagery as well. Documentation for the Bing Maps V7 JavaScript control can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx

An interactive SDK can be found here: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7

There is also a number of useful modules for Bing Maps that add features like support for GeoJSON files here: https://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/